# Opencart adding a new field to the customer view of the admin section

Tags: php, opencart

I have added a new field to my database. I also have managed to add necessary codes and functions in catalog section. This new field is related to the customer. The data related to this new field gets added successfully to the database.

This new field belongs to `Customer` table.

Now, I want to know, when viewing customer's details in the admin section, how this new field should be retrieved from database? I mean which file should be edited for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

`getCustomer($customer_id)` and `getCustomers($data = array())` are the functions used to get customer data.

Since they are `SELECT *` querys your field is being processed automatically.

Afterwards you need to go in the Controller section in the ***controller\sale*** folder and there you have customer.php, custom_field.php and and edit the ones that you need. For example:

```
$this->data['customers'][] = array(
                'customer_id'    => $result['customer_id'],
                'name'           => $result['name'],
                'email'          => $result['email'],
                'customer_group' => $result['customer_group'],
                'status'         => ($result['status'] ? $this->language->get('text_enabled') : $this->language->get('text_disabled')),
                'approved'       => ($result['approved'] ? $this->language->get('text_yes') : $this->language->get('text_no')),
                'ip'             => $result['ip'],
                'date_added'     => date($this->language->get('date_format_short'), strtotime($result['date_added'])),
                'selected'       => isset($this->request->post['selected']) && in_array($result['customer_id'], $this->request->post['selected']),
                'action'         => $action
            );
```

add your field in this array (this is from customer.php).

And finally edit the .tpl files that are called from the ***view\template\sale*** folder so they appear where they want them to.

Hope i was clear enough.